# Want to add timestamp to Center align textview with adjusting label to Right align

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, textview, ios8

In one of my Chatting app i have used label and textview. UITextView is center Align and one more label add to subview and adjusting there position according text that is working fine..

But my need is to make it similar to whatsapp application. if text is to small and label can adjust within same line than bubble should not expand to two line and adjust in single line..

i have attached image that will clear the requirement. 
[image: Want timeStamp similar to whatsapp app]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to perform this with help of **Textkit- exclusionPaths.**

```
    CGSize sizelbl = _lbl_Timestamp.frame.size;
[_lbl_Timestamp
 setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(_txtView.frame) - sizelbl.width - 5,
                     CGRectGetMaxY(_txtView.frame) - sizelbl.height - 5 - 3,
                     sizelbl.width, sizelbl.height)];


CGRect ovalFrame = [_txtView convertRect:_lbl_Timestamp.bounds fromView:_lbl_Timestamp];

// Since text container does not know about the inset, we must shift the frame to container coordinates
ovalFrame.origin.x -= _txtView.textContainerInset.left;
ovalFrame.origin.y -= _txtView.textContainerInset.top;

// Simply set the exclusion path
UIBezierPath *ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: ovalFrame];
_txtView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[ovalPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution**:

```
- (void) updateLabelFrame {

    /* self.label.frame is your required label */

    CGRect lblRect = self.label.frame;
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(self.label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

    /* Get exptected rect for label */
    CGRect labelRect = [self.label.text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.label.font} context:nil];

    /* Caculate number of lines for label */
    CGFloat labelHeight = labelRect.size.height;
    int lines = labelHeight / 16; /* 16 is Default label height, Change with your pre-set label height */ 
    [self.label setNumberOfLines:lines];

    /* Set height of your label */
    lblRect.size.height = labelHeight;
    [self.label setFrame:lblRect];

    /* Change here your view height according to label height */

    NSString *trimmedText = [self.label.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if ([trimmedText length] > 0) {

        CGFloat viewHeight = self.label.frame.origin.y + self.label.frame.size.height + /* ADD PADDING SPACE */ 20;

        CGRect viewRect = self.frame; /* SET VIEW FRAME */
        viewRect.size.height = viewHeight;
        [self setFrame:viewRect];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ans but actually my problem is if you refer above image supporse black color text is UItextview and light green timestamp is my label. how to get that text is filled with right most area in full textview so i will upade label to bottom postion. else i will not give extra space for label and add above textview.